# how to create multiple "CSS Gooey Menu" on the same page?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to use "CSS Gooey Menu" posted here:

codepen.io/lbebber/pen/pvwZJp.

I want to make multiple menus on the same page, but while I repeat the menu code and click on the new menu it still shows the first menu items as seen on the picture:

[image: picture]

What can I do to get over this problem?

Comment: post the code you have

Comment: The code is too long to post it can be found & viewed here [link]https://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/pvwZJp I just want to repeat the menu correctly. I want to make both of them works my problem is that when i repeats the <nav> code the new menu doesn't work even when it clicked the menu items of the first one appears. thanks

Comment: Post an [mcve], othewise your issue is unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: You need to post an example of what you are doing, this isn't a place for people to write your code for you. But If I understand you correctly, I think you just need to make sure the duplicate menus have a unique `id="menu-open"` and `for="menu-open`

Comment: @BrandonW Actually, I attached picture of an example which i was working on. I did not attached the code because it is too long so i attached a link for it. thanks for your help that was what i exactly mean. the menus are working perfectly now.